# Could unramified Galois groups satisfy a version of property tau?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, galois-theory, expander-graphs, spectral-gap

This is an experiment:  there is a question I want to mention in an article I'm writing, and I am not sure it's a sensible question, so I will ask it here first, in the hopes that if it's insensible someone will tell me.  If, on the other hand, the question is sensible, and someone on MO has something interesting to say about it, all the better!

So here is the question.  Let S be a finite set of primes $p_1, \ldots, p_k$.  Let G be the Galois group of the maximal totally real extension of Q unramified away from S.  We want to ask whether G satisfies a version of property tau.  What this means is a little tenuous; just to start with, we don't even know (at least I think we don't) whether G is topologically finitely generated.  Here's one possible definition:

(E):  There exists a constant c such that, for every finite totally real extension K/Q, and every k-tuple $g_1, .. g_k \in Gal(K/Q)$ such that $g_i$ lies in an inertia group over p_i and the $g_1, .. g_k$ together generate Gal(K/Q), the Cayley graph on Gal(K/Q) with generators $g_1, .. g_k$ has spectral gap at least c.

Is (E)  plausible?  Is (E) even the right notion of "expanding" for unramified Galois groups?

**Update:** A discreet friend points out that the question is indeed insensible the way I phrased it, because you could take K/Q to be the real subfield of the cyclotomic extension by p^n-th roots.  So instead of demanding that K/Q be totally split at $\infty$, it would be better to fix some other prime $\ell$ outside S and require that K/Q split there; that should re-sensibilize the problem.  Alternatively, one could drop any kind of splitting requirement and instead ask that K/Q be at worst *tamely* ramified at the primes in S; this has the additional advantage of tightening the analogy with the function field case.

**Update 2:**  After further thought, I've decided that my favorite version of this question is to ask whether:

For each k, there exists a constant $c_k$ such that, for any Galois extension K/Q which is unramified outside S and tamely ramified at S, and any k-tuple $(g_1, \ldots, g_k)$ generating $G$, the corresponding Cayley graph has spectral gap at most $c_k$.

I don't know whether this is true but I'm pretty sure I don't know that it's false.

Comment: @Will: I do not understand your comment.The extension you propose is ramified at a lot of primes outside of $S$. If you look at the remark before Theorem 10.2.5 in Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg's _Cohomology of Number Fields_, you see thinks are slightly tricker. Indeed, one can prove that $G_S^\text{ab}$ is indeed topologically finitely generated and your extensions are abelian.

Comment: @ JSE: Can you give some references for a non-expert who never heard about Cayley graphs and spectral gaps? What is the tau ($\tau$?) property?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking backwards, in terms of extensions ramified only outside of $S$, instead of only at $S$. That was silly.

Comment: @Filippo: What is property tau?
http://www.ams.org/notices/200506/what-is.pdf


Comment: @Filippo: See also Agol's answer to
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31116/books-that-discuss-spectral-graph-theory-and-its-connection-to-eigenvalue-problem

Comment: @Alain: Thanks, I'll read and I'll try to understand JSE's question... (and thanks for letting me feel so shamefully ignorant ;-))

Comment: @ JSE,Alain: Could you explain (or point to) the relation between spectral gap and expanding constant?

Comment: That's a weird definition and it would help if you motivated it. Does it salvage the function field case? In particular, with T and tau, the spectral gap depends on the choice of the generators - why did you reverse the quantifiers? Also, do you expect not only that the group should be topologically finitely generated, but should have $k$ generators of that form?

Comment: Yes, this is a good point about dependence on choice of generators.  The fact that c depends only on k, not the generators, is meant to mimic a stronger condition that is expected to hold for (e.g.) groups of Lie type -- there is expected to be a uniform spectral gap for a pairs of generators of SL_2(F_p), for instance (doesn't matter which 2 generators or what p is.)
 

Comment: Re topologically finitely generated -- I'm not sure what to expect!  If I knew that there were inertial elements at each prime which generated a dense subgroup, I would just ask that the discrete group they generate has tau with respect to the finite quotients of G, which is a more "customary" definition.

Comment: @Filippo: The relation between spectral gap and expansion constant was, I think, first noticed by Margulis in 1973. It is explained in Lubotzky's wonderful book ``Discrete groups, expanding graphs, and invariant measures''
http://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=1bn-ME3yIDAC&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=a.+lubotzky+discrete+groups+expanding+graphs+and+invariant+measures&ots=wc6AIlFJ0W&sig=pUpb5yHsb2IjM6E91bbt7CxZ_eA#v=onepage&q=a.%20lubotzky%20discrete%20groups%20expanding%20graphs%20and%20invariant%20measures&f=false

Comment: If the existence of generators would make you ask that question, ask it now (plus the question of generators), but also ask the other question as one that avoids the issue......But conjecturing the existence of such generators don't simplify everything, since the answer could, in theory, depend on the choice of generators, even generators of that form, unless there's something great about that form of generators, in which case that's the motivation I asked for above. (The product of $A_n$ has generators which disagree about relative tau.)