# Are Galois groups of Q with restricted ramification supposed to be finitely generated?

Tags: open-problems, nt.number-theory

Fix a finite set $S$ of places of $\mathbb Q$. Let $G_{\mathbb Q,S}$ be the Galois group of the maximal extension of $\mathbb Q$ unramified outside S$. I [believe](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63029/finitely-generated-galois-groups) that it is an open question whether this group is topologically finitely generated, that is, contains a dense, finitely generated subgroup.

> Is there a standard conjecture about whether $G_{\mathbb Q,S}$ should be finitely generated or not?
>   Has anyone published an opinion?

[JSE mentions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107817/could-unramified-galois-groups-satisfy-a-version-of-property-tau) a stronger conjecture: $|S|$ generators suffice; further, the existence of a special set of generators labeled by $S$ and inert at the labeling place. Is this refinement standard? (Note that a finite extension would suffice to disprove this hypothesis.)

Weakening the hypothesis, we could restrict the ramification at $S$ to be tame.

Comment: This seems to be an old conjecture of Shafarevich. This much is mentioned in Barry Mazur's article in "Modular Forms and Fermat's Last Theorem."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can look at page 532 of (the first version of) J. Neukirch, A. Schmidt, K. Wingberg, *Cohomology of Number Fields*, Springer, 1999. They explicitly write that we do not even know precisely what to conjecture for arbitrary number field. They also add "many mathematicians (including the authors) tend to think of $G_S$ as being not finitely generated". In their notation, $G_S$ is the Galois group of the maximal unramified outside of $S$ extension of a number field $K$ which has been fixed once and for all (and $S$ is finite). I do not know if the special case $K=\mathbb{Q}$ is somehow different, but I doubt it (after all, their $G_S$ is a subgroup of your $G_{\mathbb{Q},S'}$ for $S'=S\cap\mathrm{Ram}(K/\mathbb{Q})$...)

Comment: For the second edition, it's on page 623.

Comment: WOW! Ninety pages more. I hope they are not all taken by the preface to the second edition...

Comment: Surprising. I thought that it was widely believed
 that those groups were finitely generated.



Comment: One (secondary) question remains: was the finite generation really a conjecture of Shafarevich (and then, where), or is Mazur's saying so in "modular forms and Fermat's last theorem" a mistake ?

Comment: I honestly do not know. Do you have a precise reference for Mazur saying so, is it in the "Deformations" paper?

Comment: FAE: on page 246 of the Deformation Theory paper (1997) that VD and Joël cited, Mazur says: "It is not even known whether or not $G_{K,S}$ is finitely generated as a topological group (although this has been conjectured by Shafarevich about thirty years ago)."